# PHP Wordpress, Where to put code that runs when

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I followed [this guide](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job) on how to disable the standard Wordpress method of running cron jobs and running it at an interval, but I do not know where to put the code for what I want to be ran when cron jobs runs. Right now the code I want to run is in functions.php and I do not think it is being called at the interval that cron job is set for. I am 100% sure that cron job is set up right, too, for every 15 minutes.

To rephrase, I have cron jobs running wp-cron.php every 15 minutes instead of the standard 'vrtiaul cron' method Wordpress uses. Putting code in wp-cron.php doesn't seem to work and I want to run some code when cron job runs. Where do I put the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around. Hopefully it will help any newbies in the future that find themselves in a similar situation. Since I couldn't figure out how to make an event and deal with all of that jazz, I just made a cron job to visit the site which calls the standard elements, so I just put my custom code in functions.php. This is the cron job code

```
wget -q -O - http://yoursite.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Feels like I am missing a lot of knowledge and it might give me slightly wrong information for Google Analytics in the future, but it works and requires no coding.